# Delete duplicated according values in Pandas

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe like that

```
id   col1 

2   T 

2   T 

4   R

4   T

6   G

6   G
```

I want deduplicate with this way :

If I have T and T for the same id I want to keep the 2 lines

If I have G or R and G or R for the same id I want to keep the 2 lines

If I have T and (G or R) for the same IT I just want to keep the line with T (delete one of the two lines)

I want this result :)

```
id   col1 

2   T 

2   T 

4   T

6   G

6   G
```

Thank you :)

Comment: `have G or R and G or R` - not typo ? There are alwyas 2 values per groups? Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. 10 -15 rows with multiple groups where some values are removed and some not?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
m1 = df['col1'].eq('T')
m2 = m1.groupby(df['id']).transform('sum').ne(1)
df = df[m1 | m2 ]
print (df)
   id col1
0   2    T
1   2    T
3   4    T
4   6    G
5   6    G
```

**Explanation**:

Compare `col1` for `T` with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`):

```
m1 = df['col1'].eq('T')
print (m1)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Count `True` values per groups by [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum`:

```
print (m1.groupby(df['id']).transform('sum'))
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Compare for not equal by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`):

```
m2 = m1.groupby(df['id']).transform('sum').ne(1)
print (m2)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

And chain together by `|` for bitwise OR:

```
print (m1 | m2)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```